# Convert a MatLab.mat file to text file for CNN training data.

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, darknet

I'm looking to use the pose data from these sites:

- https://bensapp.github.io/flic-dataset.html
- http://human-pose.mpi-inf.mpg.de/#overview

But all the ground truth data is MatLab form, I'm trying to use the [YOLO](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) network to try and classify these images however, YOLO requires the ground truth labels to be text file format. Any idea how to do this?  Basically my aim is to try and train the YOLO network with these images by converting their ground truth to the required format and find the limbs and joints in these images.